# Is it normal for a padawan to address a Jedi Knight as "Master"?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, revenge-of-the-sith

Toward the end of Episode III when Darth Vader is in the Jedi Temple wreaking havoc with the 501st Legion, he enters a room where many of the padawans are hiding. One of them asks him, "Master Skywalker, what are we going to do?" Anakin was never given the title of Master by the council.

Was this just something padawans were supposed to do? Address those more learned in the Force as Master, regardless of their 'rank'?

Comment: IIRC, no. But can you REALLY expect a 5 year old to grasp detailed politics of Jedi Council? Previously, no Knight was made a Council member. And Anakin was a famous thing.

Answer (score 4):

"Master" is a title of respect. Remember, that a Jedi Knight can be the master
of a Padawan, so they can be masters without the actual rank.

Also, non-Jedi have used the ranks interchangeably; the Kaminoans and a protocol droid have both done so in the films.

Comment: this answer + sources = my upvote :)